# How to add a name from a textbox to a listbox from multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, sockets, concurrency

The scenario is you open up the server and begins to listen for clients on threads I'm using winforms to connect each thread into a userlist but its proving confusing so far.

I've been using the internet to get an answer to my problem but getting a migraine headache because its driving me insane.

Please Help any help would be appreciated

Gaz :)

```
private delegate void updateList(string text);

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.txtNickname.InvokeRequired)
        {
            updateList ul = new updateList(SetText);
            this.Invoke(ul, new object[] { text});
        }
        else
        {
            this.txtNickname.Text = text;
            userList.Items.Add(this.txtNickname.Text);
        }
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!granted)
        {
            granted = connected.Connect(this, "127.0.0.1", 4444, txtNickname.Text);
            if (granted)
            {
                btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";

                if (this.txtNickname.Text != " ")
                {
                    userList.Items.Add(txtNickname.Text);
                    this.txtNickname.Focus();
                    this.txtNickname.Clear();                        
                }
            }
            else
            {
                connected.Disconnect();
                granted = false;
                btnConnect.Text = "Connect";

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where SetText() is getting called, but I do see two places where the text is being added to userList.Items. Where does that incoming text actually come from? That is probably the place to call SetText().

Comment: hi thanks for the reply that was a final try to get it to work as i was looking at all possibililties from my current knowledge. the things i tried so far was invoke the userlist by adding to the nickname textbox to the list box but its only for one client and not for the other. so i need multiple threads linking to all client listboxes but no info on the internet this far.